# Conectar una directorio activo o LDAP con PHP

Tags: php, windows, ldap, centos7

Estoy intentando conectar el directorio activo o LDAP de window con una aplicacion( [GLPI](http://glpi-project.org) ) realizada en PHP.

Parametros de conexion:

```
$ds = ldap_connect($host, $port) // me retorna verdadero

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

@ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_DEREF, $deref_options);
```

**Relacionar conexión con el servidor y usuario y clave**

`ldap_bind($ds, $login, $password)` me devuelve:

> "Can't contact LDAP server" ( No puedo contactar al servidor LDAP )

Quiero saber que puede pasar con ese mensaje de  error, ya  que en el primero método me retorna  verdadero, que quiere decir que si conecta al servidor.

`RootDN` *Esta bien y tiene todo los permisos el usuario que estoy utilizando.*

El servidor por defecto esta bien ya le hice un `ping` y `telnet`.

Por favor, si me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

**Nota:** Ya descarge LDAPExplorer y establecí conexión sin problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listo, la solución a  mi problema es actualizar de versión de GLPI 9.3.0 a 9.3.3.

Sugerencias:

- Para los usuarios, que le pueda pasar esto, verificar los mensajes que GLPI tiene informa de paquetes pendientes de instalación. Así que opté, por realizar la actualización y funciono la conexión sin problema.
- Para los usuario que no puede hacer actualización de versión, verificar que paquetes de apache están pendientes por instalar o actualizar, también en el proceso de instalación en el setup(preparar), tener mucho cuidado instalando toda la lista que parece pendiente.

Para soluciona algunos errores instalando la versión 9.3.3:

```
chown -R apache:apache glpi/files

chmod -R 755 glpi/files

chown -R apache:apache config

chmod -R 755 glpi/config
```

tambien:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: Listo compa, gracias.

Comment: El comando setsebool activa o desactiva Booleanos, al opción -P es para hacer los cambios persistentes (sin este parámetro, al reiniciar se perderá el cambio) y x es on o 1 para activar, u off o 0 para desactivar. (http://francisconi.org/linux/comandos/setsebool)

Comment: agregalo a la respuesta y explica lo que dices en el comentario, trata de buscasr un comando de paginas oficiales